# Potential energy in the gravitational field - Why is $r_2$ striving against infinity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, conventions

why is $r_2$ striving against infinity in the formula $ = (\frac{1}{_1}−\frac{1}{_2})$, so its often simplified to $ = \frac{}{r}$ ?

I know that in the final formula, r is the distance between two masses, but what is $r_1$ and $r_2$ and how do they get simplified?

Also, if I want to see, if I could escape the gravitational field, why would I choose the Potential Energy $E_{pot} = (\frac{1}{_1}−\frac{1}{_2})$ and equate it to $E_{kin} = \frac{1}{2}v^2$
instead of just calculating weight force and then decide if a human can bring up this force?

Comment: where did you get that extremely incorrect expression for weight?

Answer (score 1):

Your first formula represents the work done (by integrating the force over distance) to move a small mass from radius 1 to a different radius 2 relative to a much larger mass.  This gives the change in potential energy.  To define the potential energy at a point, you must choose a reference point where it is zero.  In this case, chosing radius 1 as the reference point at infinity, gives a simpler (negative) result.
(The potential rises from a negative value toward zero as you go up.)

Comment: This is the thing I did not get in class and still don't get. This definition of the potential energy with the reference point... I understand that the further away your position is from a huge mass, the smaller is the gravitational force and thus: if the distance is infinity the potential is getting close to 0 from a negative value. But what about this reference point? Don't you always take infinity as reference where there's no Potential energy?